# Finding how many a specific digit appears in array of numbers (C++)

Tags: c++, arrays, numbers, digit

I'm doing an online challenge and the challenge is the following:
"Kids are playing a game called "Counting digits". For given numbers S and K, they firstly write all numbers between those numbers and then count how many times each digit appears (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9). For example, S=767, K=772, numbers will be: 767,768,769,770,771,772

So, 0 will show once (in 770), 1 will show once (in 771) and so on..

Basically, my program have to do the following (given example):

Input:
1 9
(These are numbers 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)

Output:
0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
(0 doesn't show, other numbers show once)."

I'm stuck on this code... out of ideas.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int s,k;
    int array[10];
    int c0=0,c1=0,c2=0,c3=0,c4=0,c5=0,c6=0,c7=0,c8=0,c9=0;
    cin >> s >> k;
    int saves = s;
    int savek = k;
    cout << s%10;
    for(int i=s;i<=k;i++)
    {
        int savei=i;
        while(savei!=0)
        {
            savei=savei%10;
        }
    }
```

Any pseudo code/snippet/code/hint is appreciated.

Comment: What if the number contains multiple digits? For example 770 ?

Comment: There's two ways to do it. One is to use `sprintf()` to convert each number to a string, then count the digits in the string. The other is to use division and modulus to get each digit from the number, and count them. In either case, you need an array `count[10]` to contain the counters of each digit.

Comment: BTW, the termination condition in your `for` loop should be `i<=k`, since your endpoints are inclusive.

Comment: while(val)
{int dig = val % 10;val /= 10; /*do stuff with dig*/
}

Comment: @X-Factor What are you talking about? He's not trying to find a digit, he wants to count how many times every digit is used in a series of numbers.

Comment: I have updated my current code in OP. Please check if it's correct and my point is to basically do %10 by all numbers and add an if or switch for each digit? Is it gonna work this way|?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Purely numeric solution to a purely numeric problem:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int s, k, i, tmp;
    std::cin >> s >> k;

    int count[10] = { 0 };

    for (i = s; i <= k; i++) {
        tmp = i;
        do {
            count[tmp % 10]++;
            tmp /= 10;
        } while(tmp);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        std::cout << i << " appears " << count[i] << " times" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Interesting.. basically I was going for the same way. Oh and it's you again. I would like to ask a few questions. What is while(tmp)? I know tmp is the temporary value of i, does that means that since 0=false, it will run as long as the value of tmp(i) doesn't become 0? Another interesting code I found in your example is count[tmp%10], I didn't know that you can do math inside the [] arrays. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @JohnSmith Of course you can, the grammar is recursive :P And no, `tmp` is a *copy* of `i`, since `tmp` is being modified (basically it goes through the digits of the number).

Comment: You never fail to amaze me, sir. Past few days, I learnt quite a lot from you. Thank you for that.

Comment: Is this your first programming language? I don't know of any common language that doesn't allow putting an expression in an array index.

Comment: @Barmar Yeah, it's quite common (because it's logical and convenient) to allow proper expressions to be used as indices, not only constants (else we'd have a hard time implementing/using `arr[i]`...)

Answer (score 1):

My solution is like this:

```
int main(){
    int s,k;
    cin >> s >> k;
    int numbers[10]={0};
    string sum;

    for(int i=s;i<=k;i++)
    {
        sum=to_string(i);
        for(int i=0;i<sum.length();i++){
            numbers[(int)sum.at(i)-48]++;
        }
    }

    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        cout<<numbers[i]<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If so, you could do it without converting to and from strings. This is a math problem, and one shall not use strings to solve it.

Comment: Should the for loop also be i<=k, since k number also is in the array.

Comment: OK. I fixed my solution. I didn't realize that k number is also in array.

Comment: I like your solution, although as H2CO3 said, this is more of a math problem. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void getDigitsInBook(int n) {
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
        int x = n,val=0,k=1;
        while(x!=0) {
            int left  = x/10;
            int num = x%10;
            int right = n%k;
            if(i == 0) {
                val = val+ (left*k);
            }
            else if(i<num) {
                val = val + ((left+1)*k);
            }
            else if(i==num) {
                val = val + (left*k) + right+1;
            }
            else {
                val = val+ (left*k);
            }
            k=k*10;
            x = n/k;
        }
        System.out.println(val);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you usually do with such tasks is calculating the number between `0` and `S` and between `0` and `K` and subtracting those.

How many are between `0` and `767`? First count the numbers of the last digit. There are `77` times 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 each and `76` times 8 and 9. More formally, `767/10+1` between `0` and `767%10` and `767/10+1` on the rest.  Then calculate the number of occurences of the last digit for `767/10=76`, multiply by `10`, add `7` times 7 and 6 (for the error on the last one) and do the same for the remaining digits, here `76/10=7`. Finally, add the results up.

This solves the problem in `O(log_10 K)`.

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
for(int n=s ; n<=k ; n++)
{
    tempN = abs(n);
    while(tempN > 0)
    {
        tempDigit = tempN % 10;
        tempN /= 10;

        //count tempDigit here
    }
}
```

assuming your variables are ints, "tempN /= 10;" should be no problem.